# Images are not displayed into the react-vs-timeline

Tags: reactjs, vis.js-timeline

Following are the code sandbox URL for the react-visjs-timeline.

Once run the URL it will displays the timeline with images.
[Timeline with images](https://codesandbox.io/s/m32n7l13zy)
It shows only first images displayed the rest of the two are not displayed because of giving the URL relative.

Could some one let me know why the second and third URL is not showing the images and how to display the tool tip on that.

Thanks

Comment: Please move your images to public folder and it will work. https://codesandbox.io/s/oov7xlnzyq. The path you entered are relative to index.html of public and not component jsx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you have used src folder for images. You must use src folder to host your css and js files -not images- in order to make them accessible by Webpack. Otherwise, **Webpack can not see them**.

In your case, you can use public folder which is directly accessed by index.html.